# How to understand the specific XSLT output

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I have below XML

```
<root>
  <Example>
    <ESell>true</ESell>
    <Details>
      <Item tc="101"/>
      <SellStatus>AAA</SellStatus>
    </Details>
    <Details>
      <Item tc="102"/>
      <SellStatus>BBB</SellStatus>
    </Details>
  </Example>
  <Story>
    <Book tc="Horror"/>
    <Cover tc="Paper"/>
    <TransRef/>
  </Story>
</root>
```

This is my XSLT change. I need to fit this into an existing XSLT. So need do this in the below mentioned way only by using Param and for-each loop.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl"
>
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="/root">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="Example"/>
    <xsl:call-template name="SellDetailsInfo">
      <xsl:with-param name="Example" select="Example">
      </xsl:with-param>
    </xsl:call-template>
  </xsl:template>
    
  <xsl:template name="SellDetailsInfo">
    <xsl:param name="Example"/>
    <xsl:for-each select="$Example/Details">
        <xsl:value-of select="$Example"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="$Example/Details"/>
      </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>
  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

If I check the value of $Example, it contains all the value but whenever I am checking the value if $Example/Details, its only printing 1st value but twice.

Output for $Example

true

AAA

BBB

true

AAA

BBB

Output of  $Example/Details is

AAA

AAA

Output of $Example/Details/SellStatus is

AAAAAA

I am new to XSLT. I tried many ways but still not able to understand the behavior.

I will use the field $Example/Details/SellStatus in <xsl:if> to check the value. If the value will be BBB then I will add some more tag to the XML.

But this is always giving me AAA.

This is XSLT 1.0

Answer (score 1):

You can remove the first `xsl:apply-templates`, because it creates the doubles. Calling the template by name is not necessary, but I leave it there, because I benevolently assume that you intend to structure your (possibly more complex) code. I also changed the name of the parameter from `Example` to `ExampleParam` to avoid confusion/name clashes.

Applying all of this and including an `xsl:if` clause, your code could look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

  <xsl:template match="/root">
    <xsl:call-template name="SellDetailsInfo">
      <xsl:with-param name="ExampleParam" select="Example" />
    </xsl:call-template>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template name="SellDetailsInfo">
    <xsl:param name="ExampleParam"/>
    <xsl:for-each select="$ExampleParam/Details">
        Details: <xsl:value-of select="SellStatus"/>
        <xsl:if test="SellStatus='BBB'">
          SubDetails: <xsl:value-of select="'whatever'"/>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Its output is

```
Details: AAA
Details: BBB
  SubDetails: whatever
```

Comment: Thank you for the help. Its working. I can now modify this based on my further requirement.

Answer (score 1):

The output you get could be divided into 2 parts:

The first part is produced by the instruction:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="Example"/>
```

You do not have a template matching `Example`, so the [built-in template rules](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xslt-19991116/#built-in-rule) process the `Example` element and copy all of its descendant text nodes to the output to produce:

```
    true
    
        
        AAA
    
    
        
        BBB
```

The 2nd part is produced by calling the `SellDetailsInfo` template. This template iterates over both `Details` elements, and produces **exactly** the same output for both of them. Why? Because your `xsl:value-of` instructions refer to the `$Example` parameter, not to the current `Detail`.

Therefore the first instruction:

```
<xsl:value-of select="$Example"/>
```

returns the string-value of the entire `Example` element (which is again the concatenation of  all the text node descendants of `Example`), and the 2nd instruction:

```
<xsl:value-of select="$Example/Details"/>
```

returns the string-value of the first `Details` element - this is because in XSLT 1.0 the `xsl:value-of` instruction returns the string-value of the first node in the selected node-set.

Hopefully this will help you to understand why you're getting the output that you see. You did not say what output you want to get, so I am not going to guess what might be the best way to get it. Especially since I don't understand your limitation of "fit this into an existing XSLT" or why you need (or think you need) to "do this in the below mentioned way only by using Param and for-each loop."

Comment: I have tried many things but was not able to understand. Thank you once again.